# A problem about holomorphic functions not continuous to the boundary.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck in the the following argument. I believe the following to be true but not able to prove.

Let $\varphi_i\in\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{D}),\,i=1,\,2.$ Fix a point $p\in\partial\mathbb{D}.$ Suppose there exist sequences, $\{z_\nu^i\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+},\,i=1,2,$ converging to $p$ such that the sequences, $\{\varphi_i(z_\nu^i)\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+},\,i=1,2,$ converges in $\mathbb{D}.$ Furthermore the sequences $\{\varphi_1(z_\nu^2)\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ and $\{\varphi_2(z_\nu^1)\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ converges to the boundary of $\mathbb{D}.$

Claim: There exists a sequence $\{z_\nu\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$which converges to $p$ such that $\{\varphi_i(z_\nu)\}_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+},\,i=1,2$ converges in $\mathbb{D}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Furthermore the sequences $\{\varphi_1(z_2^\nu)\}$ and $\{\varphi_2(z_1^\nu)\}$ converges to the boundary of D.

Side remark: if either of these sequences had a limit point in $\mathbb D$, we would be done already. So this condition does not really add extra information.

Here is a counterexample. Choose an increasing sequence $x_n\nearrow 1$ inductively, so that the hyperbolic distance $\rho(x_n,x_{n+1})$ rapidly tends to infinity. For example, 
$$\log\left|\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{1-x_{n+1}x_n}\right|>-\frac{1}{2^n} \tag1$$
Consider the Blaschke products
$$\phi_1(z)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z-x_{2k-1}}{1-x_{2k-1}z},\quad
\phi_2(z)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z-x_{2k}}{1-x_{2k}z} \tag2$$
Clearly, $\phi_1(x_{2k-1})=0$ and $\phi_2(x_{2k})=0$ for all $k$. On the other hand, there is **no**  sequence $z_\nu$  converging to $p$, such that  $$\limsup_{\nu\to\infty}\max(|\phi_1(z_\nu)|,|\phi_2(z_\nu)|)<1 \tag3$$
Indeed, from (1) and $\log |\phi_1(z_\nu)|<-\epsilon<0 $ it follows that the hyperbolic distance from $z_\nu$ to the set $\{x_{2k-1}:k\in\mathbb N\}$ remains bounded as $\nu\to\infty $. The same applied to $\phi_2$ implies that the hyperbolic distance from $z_\nu$ to   $\{x_{2k }:k\in\mathbb N\}$ remains bounded. This contradicts our choice of $x_n$.

Comment: In the first equation, the expression in right side, is it the formula for the hyperbolic distance? I'm asking this as if by the hyperbolic distance if you mean Poincare distance, then the formula is not correct, but yes the points could be chosen as you said.

Comment: @Abelvikram Although I thought of this example in terms of the hyperbolic (Poincare) distance, it is not used in computations. So I did not write it down at all. Instead, I wrote (1), which expresses the fact that hyperbolic distance rapidly increases, in a form more suitable for working with Blaschke products.

Comment: can you please provide a little bit motivatation for your answer , I mean what is the idea before I check the details? Thanks.

Comment: @Abelvikram The idea is that a Blaschke product with zeros placed apart from one another satisfies $|\phi(z)|\to 1$ when the hyperbolic distance from $z$ to the set of zeros tends to infinity.  Equivalently, $|\phi(z)|<1-\epsilon$ requires $z$ to be within a bounded hyperbolic distance from the zero set. Then one picks two such zero sets which are far apart from one another in hyperbolic metric.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: I think I got your idea for I'm not completely sure. I'm busy with some work, so I'll make sure latter that if I understood your answer completely. But Thanks anyway.