# Is there any inner function that satisifies the following boundary conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{w_n\}$ and $\{z_n\}$ ($w_n\neq z_n,\forall n$) be two complex sequences in the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ with the same cluster point $\zeta\in\partial\mathbb{D}$. Is there any inner function $S_\zeta$, such that $S_\zeta(w_n)$ and $S_\zeta(z_n)$ has different limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, take $w_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $z_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Even if you require $w_n\ne z_m$ for all $n,m$, the answer is still no. By [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula) applied to a slightly smaller disk $r\mathbb D$ ($0<r<1$), any holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ satisfies 
$$|f'(z)|\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial r D} \frac{|f(\xi)|}{|\xi-z|^2}\,d\xi \le \frac{1}{(r-|z|)^2} \tag1$$
Letting $r\to 1$ in (1) yields
$$|f'(z)|\le  \frac{1}{(1-|z|)^2} \tag2$$
Therefore, if $w_n$ and $z_n$ are such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|w_n-z_n|}{(1-\max(|z_n|,|w_n|)^2} =0 \tag2$$
integration of $f'$ along the line segment from $z_n$ to $w_n$ yields
$$
|f(z_n)-f(w_n)|\to 0 \quad \text{as } \ n\to\infty \tag3
$$

---

If you can choose $z_n$ and $w_n$, such an example can be constructed: see [A problem about holomorphic functions not continuous to the boundary.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424234/79365)

Comment: Thanks. We may choose $w_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $z_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ since $w_n\rightarrow\partial\mathbb{D}$ and $z_n\rightarrow\partial\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @Cezhong-Tong Thanks, I corrected the formulas.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula works only when $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ can be extended continuously to the boundary. Your answer seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I am wrong. Your answer should be correct. First let integral path be $r\partial\mathbb{D}$ $\forall r\in(0,1)$, then take the limits respect to $r$.

Comment: @Cez You can apply the integral formula on the circle of radius $r<1$, use the boundedness of $f$ there, then pass to the limit $r\to1$ and get the same inequality for $f'$ as in my answer. I'll edit this into my answer later.

Comment: @user127096 - Thanks - I don't know what I was thinking. I'll delete my comment.